# mindmup js -How to create json format of created map using mindmap.js

Tags: javascript

Guys i am trying to create brainstorming by includes "mindmup js". i included all dependencies given in the readme file Link: https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs-webpack-example   there is json example format but unable to make own json format to store and documentation is not that much clear.if you have any examples on how to work with mindmup-to create the json. please post.your answers will be highly appreciable.